# Display different values in a popup in React

Tags: reactjs, popup

I am trying to have a popup for editing profile information in react, and I want there to be a button by each value that will allow a user to edit that specific value. The popup works, except it will only display the last value that I have put in. I think it is because I need to reset the state each time the button is clicked, but I am still fairly new to react so I am not sure how to do it.

I will add my code, however it is pulling some information from a local database, so let me know if you need me to remove things.

Here is the component for the popup

```js
import React from 'react'

const Popup = props => {
    console.log(props)
    return(
        <div className='popup-box'>
            <div className='box'>
                <span className='close-icon' onClick={props.handleClose}>x</span>
                {props.content}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Popup
```

And here is the component page where the popup appears

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { getUser } from '../apiClient'
import Nav from './Nav'
import EditPopup from './EditPopup'

export default function UserProfile (props) {

    

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    const togglePopup = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen)
        
    }

    

    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        user: []
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        getUser(props.match.params.id)
            .then((res) => {
                setUser(res)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error', error.message)
        
            })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='globalBackground'>
            <Nav />
            <div className='UserInfoForm'>
                <div className='profile-heading' >
                <h1>General User Information</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='profile-Pic' >
                    <div className='profile-pic-heading'>
                <h2>Profile Picture</h2>
                </div>
                <div className='profile-pic-display'>
                <img src={user.profilePic} style={{ width: '150px', height: '150px' }}
                alt=''
              />
              </div>
              </div>
              <div className='UsernameEdit'>
              <h2>Username</h2>
              <p>{user.username}</p>
              <input type='button' value='Edit' onClick={togglePopup} />
              {isOpen && <EditPopup
                content={<>
                <b>Edit Your Username</b>
                <div className='userNameEditInput'>
                 <input className='usernameEdit' placeholder={user.username} />
                 </div>
                    <button>Save Changes</button>
                    </>}
                        handleClose={togglePopup}
                        />}
              <div />
              <div className='EmailEdit'>
              <h2>Email</h2>
              <p>{user.email}</p>
              <input type='button' value='Edit' onClick={togglePopup} />
              {isOpen && <EditPopup
                content={<>
                <b>Edit Your Email</b>
                <div className='emailEditInput'>
                 <input className='emailEdit' placeholder={user.email} />
                 </div>
                    <button>Save Changes</button>
                    </>}
                        handleClose={togglePopup}
                        />}
              </div>
              <div className='CountryEdit'>
              <h2>Country</h2>
              <p>{user.country}</p>
              <input type='button' value='Edit' onClick={togglePopup} />
              {isOpen && <EditPopup
                content={<>
                <b>Edit Your Country</b>
                <div className='countryEditInput'>
                 <input className='countryEdit' placeholder={user.country} />
                 </div>
                    <button>Save Changes</button>
                    </>}
                        handleClose={togglePopup}
                        />}
              </div>
              <div className='RegionEdit'>
              <h2>Region</h2>
              <p>{user.region}</p>
              <input type='button' value='Edit' onClick={togglePopup} />
              {isOpen && <EditPopup
                content={<>
                <b>Edit Your Region</b>
                <div className='regionEditInput'>
                 <input className='regionEdit' placeholder={user.email} />
                 </div>
                    <button>Save Changes</button>
                    </>}
                        handleClose={togglePopup}
                        />}
              </div>
              <div className='HandicapEdit'>
              <h2>Handicap</h2>
              <p>{user.handicap}</p>
              <input type='button' value='Edit' onClick={togglePopup} />
              {isOpen && <EditPopup
                content={<>
                <b>Edit Your Handicap</b>
                <div className='handicapEditInput'>
                 <input className='handicapEdit' placeholder={user.handicap} />
                 </div>
                    <button>Save Changes</button>
                    </>}
                        handleClose={togglePopup}
                        />}
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Let me know if there's any other code needed, any help would be greatly appreciated :--)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the state from the `UserProfile` and move it inside the Popup Component.

```
import React from 'react';

const Popup = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => setToggle((prevToggle) => !prevToggle);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="button" value="Edit" onClick={togglePopup} />
      {toggle && (
        <div className="popup-box">
          <div className="box">
            <span className="close-icon" onClick={togglePopup }>
              x
            </span>
            {props.content}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Popup;
```

You can then use EditPopup as below in the UserProfile.

```
{
<div className='UsernameEdit'>
<h2>Username</h2>
<p>{user.username}</p>
<EditPopup
  content={<>
  <b>Edit Your Username</b>
  <div className='userNameEditInput'>
   <input className='usernameEdit' placeholder={user.username} />
   </div>
      <button>Save Changes</button>
  </>       
  }
  />
<div />
}
```